# Is there a way to easily reverse the merging of the master branch to the feature branch in GIT and then do the opposite?

Tags: git, git-merge

I merged the master branch with the feature branch on my local repository, but when pushing to the remote repository I somehow merged the master branch into the feature branch. Instead, I needed to merge the feature branch into the master branch on the local repository.

What steps do I need to take to ensure that I do so safely?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "safely".  For some reasonable definitions of "safe", once you have pushed to the remote you should not change the remote.  But, you are free to `reset` and `push --force` as much as you want.

Comment: By safe, I just mean not have any of the previous commits affected at all. So I would not want to lose or alter any of the previous commits and branches at all.

Comment: Undo the merge and do it again the other way round.

Comment: What commands would I need to use for that?

Comment: The first comment tells you the answer. If feature branch is the one that got the merge commit, reset it (hard) to the commit before the merge commit. Now checkout master and merge feature into it. You have now rewritten history, so you will have for force push all that of that up to the remote repository, but you claim you're okay with that.